# Expand collapse grid and adjust to page width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Grid view which is divided horizontally. Having 3 buttons which will expand and collapse grids accordingly. But it is not adjusting to the width of the page. I mean when I hide each grids, it should occupy entire page. Also the buttons i need to place in top of each place as shown in image. Also button should change + and - (Expand collapse).

What I have is

[image]

What I need is

[image]

Grid is as below

```
<button class="btnShowHide1">First</button> 
<button class="btnShowHide2">Second</button> 
<button class="btnShowHide3">Third</button> 
<div class="row col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Section 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Section 3</h3>        
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Section 4</h3>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

My detailed code is : [Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZbMVQ)

Comment: The areas are only going to take up the space you gave them, `col-lg-3` or 1/4 of the row width.  If you want them to take up more when one is hidden, adjust which `col-lg-*` class they have when one is hidden

Comment: Can you give a fiddle or codepen with updated code with + and - buttons?

Comment: Can use any two images (one for + and one for -) with 3 set of colors to identify 3 grids. It should go to left side when collapsed so color will identify which grid it corresponds to. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the classes to use `xs` for StackOverflow.

Essentially, you need to derive the class to put on the cells by the number of visible columns left.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $columns = $('.row > div');
  
  $('.btnShowHide').on('click', function () {
    var columnIndex = $(this).data('column');
    var classToRemove = 'col-xs-'+ (12 / $columns.not('.hidden').length);
    
    $columns.removeClass(classToRemove);
    $columns.eq(columnIndex).toggleClass('hidden');
    $columns.addClass('col-xs-'+ (12 / $columns.not('.hidden').length));
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnShowHide" data-column="0">First</button>
<button class="btnShowHide" data-column="1">Second</button>
<button class="btnShowHide" data-column="2">Third</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <h3>Column 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <h3>Column 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <h3>Column 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <h3>Column 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about + and - buttons?

Comment: Not working. Clicked first button it hides first section if I click again it hide others also

Comment: I do not see that behavior in this runnable snippet.  Repeated clicking of the first button only toggles the first section.

Comment: buddy that button behaviour is not there and need to be implemented. Your valuable suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://imgur.com/43fHpYO  Repeated clicking of the first button does not affect the other buttons in this snippet, at least in Firefox.  If you are using another browser and seeing an issue, please share that information.  @user1365067

Answer (score 1):

You can't just toggle `col-lg-3` and `col-lg-4`. The items would also need to be 6 or 12 columns depending on the count. You need to count the number of visible classes and apply the appropriate class to all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnShowHide1').on('click', function(){
        $('.row div:first-child').toggleClass('hidden');
        updateClasses();
    });
    $('.btnShowHide2').on('click', function(){
        $('.row div:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('hidden');
        updateClasses();
    });
    $('.btnShowHide3').on('click', function(){
        $('.row div:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('hidden');
        updateClasses();
    });
});

function updateClasses() {
    var visibleDivs = $('.row div').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).hasClass('hidden');
    });
    var colClass = 'col-lg-' + (12 / visibleDivs.length);
    $(visibleDivs).attr('class', colClass);  
}
```

Comment: what about + and - buttons?

Comment: I can't figure out from your drawing what those are supposed to do.

Comment: @ dave I mean each grid should be associated with 3 buttons with expand/collapse. Once collapsed button should move to left side to the down of the button placed there and once expand it should go back to previous position. hope you are clear.

Comment: Not clear at all. Maybe if I saw an attempted implementation of these +/- buttons I might be able to understand what you're trying to achieve. But they're missing entirely from your original code.